# Postgres: counting records in two groups (existing foreign key or null)

Tags: postgresql

I have a table `items` and a table `batches`. A batch can have n items associated by `items.batch_id`.

I'd like to write a query item counts in two groups `batched` and `unbatched`:

1. items WHERE batch_id IS NOT NULL (batched)
2. items WHERE batch_id IS NULL (unbatched)

The result should look like this

| batched | unbatched |
| --- | --- |
| 1200000 | 100 |

Any help appreciated, thank you!

EDIT:
I got stuck with using `GROUP BY` which turned out to be the wrong tool for the job.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `COUNT` with `FILTER( WHERE)

it is called conditional count

```
CREATE TABLE items(item_id int, batch_id int)
```

> ```
> CREATE TABLE
> ```

```
INSERT INTO items VALUEs(1,NULL),(2,NULL),(3,1)
```

> ```
> INSERT 0 3
> ```

```
CREATE tABLe batch (batch_id int)
```

> ```
> CREATE TABLE
> ```

```
select 
       count(*) filter (WHERE batch_id IS NOT NULL ) as "matched"
  ,
         count(*) filter (WHERE batch_id IS NULL ) as "unmatched"
from items
```

| matched | unmatched |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 |

> ```
> SELECT 1
> ```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/HRIj5xpQ)

Answer (score 1):

The `count()` function seems to be the most likely basic tool here.  Given an expression, it returns a count of the number of rows where that expression evaluates to non-null.  Given the argument `*`, it counts all rows in the group.

To the extent that there is a trick, it is getting the batched an unbatched counts in the same result row.  There are at least three ways to do that:

- Using subqueries:

```sql
select
  (select count(batch_id) from items) as batched,
  (select count(*) from items where batch_id is null) as unbatched
-- no FROM
```

That's pretty straightforward.  Each subquery is executed and produces one column of the result.  Because no `FROM` clause is given in the outer query, there will be exactly one result row.

- Using window functions:

```sql
select
  count(batch_id) over () as batched,
  (count(*) over () - count(batch_id) over ()) as unbatched
from items
limit 1
```

That will compute the `batched` and `unbatched` results for the whole table on every result row, one per row of the `items` table, but then only one result row is actually returned.  It is reasonable to hope (though you would definitely want to test) that postgres doesn't actually compute those counts for all the rows that are culled by the `limit` clause.  You might, for example, compare the performance of this option with that of the previous option.

- Using `count()` with a `filter` clause, as described in detail in [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74382307/2402272).

Comment: Thank you for the two different approaches and suggesting the benchmarking of all the different options. I'll look into it!